# Joint testing of proportions, analogous to the Hotelling $T^2$ test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, proportion, multivariate-distribution, hotelling-t2

Hotelling's $T^2$ test examine if two multivariate Gaussian distributions with the same covariance matrix have the same mean vector. Assuming the two distributions to have the same covariance matrix or even that the distributions are jointly Gaussian are (perhaps) unrealistic assumptions, but they provide a starting point for doing that kind of multivariate testing.

If Hotelling's $T^2$ test is kind of a multivariate analogue of univariate testing of two means of Gaussian distributions, what would be the analogue for proportion testing? If I want to test if New York and Chicago have the same proportions of male vs female dogs AND the same proportions of cloudy vs sunny days,$^{\dagger}$ what would be the go-to method?

$^{\dagger}$Okay, cloudy vs sunny days is probably a violation of independence, but just go with it as an example.